# O apache pode reescrever para url externa?

Tags: apache, url-rewrite

Eu tenho uma aplicação rodando no `local`. Ao mesmo tempo tenho a aplicação que já está rodando em produção - a saber uma rede social.

Tenho fotos de muitos usuários nesse sistema que está em produção, mas como não é viável colocá-las no repositório do `git`, nem copiá-las todas para o computador, gostaria de saber se há alguma maneira de fazer com que o apache reescreva a url dessa aplicação local, quando ele não encontrar a imagem (no local), para a url da aplicação que está em produção.

Seria algo mais ou menos assim:

```
local/public/teste.jpg => https//producao.com.br/public/teste.jpg
```

Comment: Conseguiu? A resp que dei ajudou?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o [P flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) em modo [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) regra para substituir URL com [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^minhaPasta/$ http://outro.exemplo.com.br/outraPasta/ [P]
```

Agora quando o cliente requisitar `/minhaPasta/` em seu servidor, ele solicitara `http://outro.exemplo.com.br/outraPasta/` e envia essa resposta ao cliente.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar o módulo [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Adicione o bloco abaixo dentro de `<VirtualHost><Directory>` no seu arquivo de configuração ou no [.htaccess](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) se o seu site tem permissão para alterar as configurações do Apache.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule "^public/(.*)" "https://www.producao.com.br/public/$1" [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Você tem que ativar o módulo caso ele ainda não esteja ativo.

Exemplo com Linux:

```
a2enmod rewrite
service apache2 restart
```

O serviço tem que ser reiniciado quando módulos são ativados/desativados. `reload`não é suficiente nesse caso.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode até fazer apenas o redirecionamento para o servidor sem reescrever, mas você pode enfrentar bloqueios com o `Referer:` ou dificuldades com o uso das imagens com canvas por exemplo, por causa do [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS).

O recomendável é usar um webproxy (usando CURL por exemplo) combinado com Apache (se acaso for usar tecnologias `canvas`, muitos plugins "html5" fazem o uso disto).

Supondo que as fotos sejam todas de um único domínio, ficaria algo como:

```
<?php
if (empty($_GET['path']) === false) {
     echo 'Caminho não definido';
     exit;
}

$path = $_GET['path'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://site-externo.com/' . $path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

//Envia o user agente do navegador atual
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

//Força retornar binario
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);

//Pega os dados
$data = curl_exec($ch);

//Fecha o curl
curl_close($ch);

$ch = NULL;

$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($data === false)
{
    http_response_code(404);
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
} elseif ($httpcode !== 200) {
    http_response_code($httpcode);
} else {
    $finfo = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);
    header('Content-Type: ' . $finfo->buffer($data));
    echo $data;
}
```

E o .htaccess deve ficar assim:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule "^local/public/(.*)" proxy.php?path=$1
```

> nota: Eu não uso muito o curl, pode ser que falte algo, me comunique se algo falhar

Comment: Informação incorreta. É possível reescrever URLs com apache e redirecionar a requisição para qualquer URL.

Comment: @Erico sem querer ofende-lo, venho a presumir que "talvez" desconheça a flag R do mod_rewrite. Na verdade o que você fez na sua resposta foi um redirecionamento, pois dois servidores diferentes não se conversam com mod_rewrite, o que ele quer é reescrever e não redirecionar. No caso ele quer que o localhost acesse um servidor externo, não é o mesmo servidor. Espero que tenha ficado claro a minha explicação :)

Comment: Guilherme, sim, o redirecionamento pode ser feito para um servidor externo, você pode testar o redirecionamento que eu postei. Ele não quer literalmente reescrever a URL, ele quer carregar as imagens do servidor de produção no servidor local caso elas não existam localmente, sem fazer qualquer alteração no código.

Comment: Guilherme, não estou dizendo que sua resposta está incorreta, estou dizendo que a informação relacionada ao apache está. Ele está rodando localmente, então a requisições virão do mesmo lugar. Se houver alguma restrição com CORS, o que eu acho pouco provável, não irá se aplicar aqui. Ele só quer carregar as imagens do site de produção, rss.

Comment: Na verdade você pode até ter tido a intenção de não dizer, mas seu texto ***"Informação incorreta."*** da a entender exatamente isto :) - Ok, veja a edição, existem problemas com CORS e HOTLINKS que são bloqueados as vezes. O uso do webproxy ajuda no trabalho ;) @Erico

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento mais uma vez: Esse é o tipo de pergunta, onde já consegui uma resposta sozinho (na base do fuçometro).  Eu fiz da seguinte forma e deu certo: `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(jpg|bmp|png)$  https://www.site.com.br/$1.$2`

Comment: @WallaceMaxters só não entendi, você ofereceu a recompensa hoje. Resolveu hoje mesmo o problema?

Comment: Não, @GuilhermeNascimento. Estou com muito pontos e queria ver essa pergunta respondida :). Além do que vai beneficiar alguém ;). Estou pra entrar de férias e estou dando um tapa em perguntas antigas

Comment: @WallaceMaxters de qualquer maneira, considere a resposta aqui como alternativa quando for usar tecnologias vulgarmente chamadas de html5 e enfrentar problemas de CORS ou tiver problemas com hotlinks, talvez seja util até pra fazer um cache com headers ;)